# Adding a function inside waypoint's sticky?

Tags: jquery

This is bugging me, I tried passing the jQuery in a scroll function, but that doesnt work. What I am trying to do is do stuff when jQuery sticky is added. LINKS TO JSFIDDLE ARE NOT ALLOWED??.

```
$('.header').waypoint('sticky', function () {

    var $demo = $(this);

    if ($demo.hasClass('stuck')) {

        alert('stuck')

    } else {

        alert('Free as a bird')

    }
```

});

I just want to do something like animate etc when `.header` has class sticky, then when it does not have the class to revert back to default state. Pretty simple, but I am having a hard time writing it with waypoints.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/ayEK9/2/ I couldnt add a jsfiddle link above IDK why, but here it is..

Answer (score 0):

Ok I should have shot more attempts before asking, I found a solution. Asking a question usually gets me more engaged and gets me thinking more. Here is a working [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ayEK9/3/). Id be happy to see your answers for fun and learning purposes, it would be cool to see other developers approaches to this, best answer (if answers are still allowed since I answered mine) gets rep!

```
$('.header').waypoint('sticky');



$(window).scroll(function() { 

    if ($('.header').hasClass('stuck')) {

        $('.header').css({background: '#eee'});

    } else {

        $('.header').css({background: '#333'});

    }

});
```

I should have thought of this from the beginning but I thought I could run the code inside the `.waypoint` function.